# Integrity constraint violation: column cannot be null, variable error

Tags: php, json, variables, constraints

Im working on a project where I need to submit new data to a mysql database. However after inserting the data and click the submit button an error appears saying the value cannot be null... but they aren´t because the values inserted appear with an echo. I dont know if the variables are declared correctly. If someone can help I´ll be gratefull :).
This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWeVU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIR9V.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mk0B.jpg)

Comment: hey. welcome to the community. In the pictures you shared, which is not recommended btw as you should always share your code as a part of the the question, you are sending the data using a CURL request and in none of them is the code that adds to the database.

However, from the curl request I can see that you're not sending the "DESCR" data but your database column states that it can NOT be null. If you have cases that this column can be null then change the null status of the column to TRUE in the database. other than that, make sure you're sending that specific column's data.

Comment: also, please share the code that inserts to the database as a part of the question in code tags. that way it's accessible to everyone on any device with copy, paste and edit capabilities and good syntax highlighting.